# preg_replace easy for a pro

Tags: php, sql, mysql, preg-replace, pcre

i want to find first select ... from and replace that only, following code replace all select..from in sql query, i just need for first select..from

```
preg_replace('#select(.*?)from#is', "select count($expr) as counted from", $sql);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fourth optional parameter called 'limit' for [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) which defines the number of replacements, and which defaults to -1 (meaning *no limit*)

```
preg_replace('#select(.*?)from#is', "select count($expr) as counted from", $sql, 1);
```